# mutate function produces unexpected results for numeric column in table (huxtable), but not in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to learn how to produce pretty tables using the package `huxtable`. It's a learning curve, but so far I am really impressed. However, I have run into a few problems that I can't seem to solve.

Firstly, I am trying to format numbers so that there is comma separator for the thousands position (using the `mutate_at` function from the `dplyr` package, and `prettyNum`. It works well except that, for columns with class numeric, internal zeros are excised (e.g., 1001 becomes 1,1 instead of the desired 1,001). If the col class is integer, then the desired output is produced. Also, the correct output is produced if the input data is a dataframe rather than a huxtable, regardless of whether the column is numeric or integer.

Secondly, when I add other table formatting (in particular, a caption), the caption does not seem to be carried over when I write the table to a Word file. Additionally, a note is produced:

`Note: zip::zip() is deprecated, please use zip::zipr() instead`

Below is some example code that I think illustrates the issue.

My questions are:

1) Why does the mutate function produce the odd result for numeric column in huxtables, but not in data frames, and how can I ensure that it does work? I could, of course, do the number formatting before converting the dataframe to a table, but I'd still like to know what is going on here.

2) Why is the table formatting not preserved in the output file?

3) What does the note about using `zipr` mean, and could that issue it references also be responsible for the failure to export table properties?

Thanks,
Glenn

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)
library(huxtable)

test=data.frame(var1=1918:1925,var2=c(9009,1000:1006),var3 = 1100:1107)
str(test)
HUX <- hux(test)
number_format(HUX)
number_format(HUX[,2]) <- 0
# works as expected on data frame
mutate_at(test,-1,.funs=list(~prettyNum(.,big.mark=",")))
# does not work as expected on huxtable, for var2 of class numeric
mutate_at(HUX,-1,.funs=list(~prettyNum(., big.mark=",")))

# add caption, borders, and colnames
set_caption(HUX,"Example table") %>%
set_caption_pos("topleft") %>%
set_top_border(1,,1) %>%
set_bottom_border(final(1), , 1)    %>%
add_colnames()

# write out the table (this produces a note about zipr)
quick_docx(HUX)
```

Comment: Re the note about using zipr see https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/454

Comment: Re `mutate_at`: huxtable doesn't implement this method - it only implements `mutate` - so unless `mutate_at` itself calls mutate, that's why it won't work. But actually, what do you mean by "does not work as expected"? It looks okay to me.

Comment: Finally, your second problem has a simple solution: you are changing all of the features of `HUX` but you're not saving the result back to the original variable. Remember that R is a functional language, objects are very rarely modified in place. Add `HUX <-` to the start of your dplyr chain

Comment: Thanks! The "number_format" solution works great. The caption still does not appear with quick_docx(HUX), but it does appear with quick_pdf(HUX). In any case, I will probably use pdf most of the time anyway. Interestingly, though, setting column widths seems to work with quick_docx, but not with quick_pdf, but I'll post another question for this issue.

Comment: See `?as_flextable` for what features Word conversion does not support…

Comment: OK, thanks. Best I can tell, captions are not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re the note about using zipr: see https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/454

Re `mutate_at`: your data is being transformed correctly, but huxtable is displaying it wrongly. It is recognising each number, before and after the comma, as separate. (Number recognition is hard, let's go shopping…) I would suggest using `number_format` instead of transforming the data directly:

```
number_format(HUX)[,2:3] <- list(function(x) prettyNum(x, big.mark=","))
```

Finally, your second problem has a simple solution: you are changing all of the features of `HUX` but you're not saving the result back to the original variable. Remember that R is a functional language, objects are very rarely modified in place. Add `HUX <-` to the start of your dplyr chain.